# Antd calendar : Click Year first and trigger to choose month forcefully

Tags: calendar, antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2qAJ.png)

i'm working on antd calendar and when i click month in panel(top right), i would like to set month part to be choose. Im working on fetching calendar date with based on YYYY/MM param so that's why i would like to make it choose both again

i have tried to manage year and month state separately but seems not working as the month dropdown does not open.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywtcg8?file=demo.tsx)
Once you select the year, the month dropdown will automatically open.
We can achieve this using `headerRender`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/zh-cn';
import type { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import dayLocaleData from 'dayjs/plugin/localeData';
import { Calendar, Col, Radio, Row, Select, Typography, theme } from 'antd';
import type { CalendarProps } from 'antd';

dayjs.extend(dayLocaleData);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();

  const onPanelChange = (value: Dayjs, mode: CalendarProps<Dayjs>['mode']) => {
    console.log(value.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), mode);
  };

  const wrapperStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    width: 300,
    border: `1px solid ${token.colorBorderSecondary}`,
    borderRadius: token.borderRadiusLG,
  };

  return (
    <div style={wrapperStyle}>
      <Calendar
        fullscreen={false}
        headerRender={({ value, type, onChange, onTypeChange }) => {
          const [isMopen, setIsMOpen] = useState(false);
          const start = 0;
          const end = 12;
          const monthOptions = [];

          let current = value.clone();
          const localeData = value.localeData();
          const months = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            current = current.month(i);
            months.push(localeData.monthsShort(current));
          }

          for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
            monthOptions.push(
              <Select.Option key={i} value={i} className="month-item">
                {months[i]}
              </Select.Option>
            );
          }

          const year = value.year();
          const month = value.month();
          const options = [];
          for (let i = year - 10; i < year + 10; i += 1) {
            options.push(
              <Select.Option key={i} value={i} className="year-item">
                {i}
              </Select.Option>
            );
          }
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
              <Typography.Title level={4}>Custom header</Typography.Title>
              <Row gutter={8}>
                <Col>
                  <Radio.Group
                    size="small"
                    onChange={(e) => onTypeChange(e.target.value)}
                    value={type}
                  >
                    <Radio.Button value="month">Month</Radio.Button>
                    <Radio.Button value="year">Year</Radio.Button>
                  </Radio.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Select
                    size="small"
                    dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
                    className="my-year-select"
                    value={year}
                    onChange={(newYear) => {
                      setIsMOpen(true);
                      const now = value.clone().year(newYear);
                      onChange(now);
                    }}
                  >
                    {options}
                  </Select>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Select
                    size="small"
                    dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
                    value={month}
                    onChange={(newMonth) => {
                      const now = value.clone().month(newMonth);
                      onChange(now);
                      setIsMOpen(false);
                    }}
                    open={isMopen}
                  >
                    {monthOptions}
                  </Select>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          );
        }}
        onPanelChange={onPanelChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```